# Prove that $u(x,t)\leq 6t+|x|^2$ for all $(x,t)\in U_T$. Here $U_T=U\times(0,T]$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> let $U$  be the unit ball in $R^3$. Suppose $u$ solves the heat equation
> $$
> \left\{\begin{matrix}
> u_t-\Delta = 0 \text{ in } U_T\\ 
> u(x,t)=6t \text{ when } |x|=1\\ 
> u(x,0)=g(x)
> \end{matrix}\right.
> $$
> Suppose that $g\leq0$. Prove that $u(x,t)\leq 6t+|x|^2$ for all $(x,t)\in U_T$. Here $U_T=U\times(0,T]$

I know that for a heat equation, there is the maximum principle.
That is $$\max\limits_{\bar{U}_T}u=\max\limits_{\Gamma_T}u$$
Where $\Gamma_T=\bar{U}_T-U_T$

But I really don't see how to apply this theorem in the above context.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
\begin{align}
U(x,t) = |x|^2+6t-u(x, t).
\end{align}
Observe that
\begin{align}
\partial_t U-\Delta U = 6-\partial_t u-(6-\Delta u) = 0
\end{align}
since $\Delta |x|^2= 2+2+2 = 6$. Note that $U(x, t) = |x|^2 = 1$ when $|x| =1$ and $U(x, 0) = |x|^2-u(x, 0)= |x|^2-g(x) \ge 0$.

Finally, by the minimum principle, we have that
\begin{align}
U(x, t) \ge 0 \ \ \implies \ \ |x|^2+6t\ge u(x, t). 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I would like a little clarification. I think I'm a bit confused about the nature of the set that we have.... To consider the values of $U(x,t)$at the boundary (that is $\Gamma_T$) can you please explain why it is enough to evaluate it for $t=0$ and $|x|=1$

Comment: First, I showed that $U$ solves the heat equation. The latter part shows that $U$ satisfies some initial and boundary conditions which are relevant for applying the minimum principle.

Comment: Thanks alot for the clarification